# iPhone 6 Plus will not open epub files

Tags: iphone, ios, books, epub

When I try to download epub files on my iPhone from the internet it used to go directly to iBooks, now it just goes to a blank page. How can I make them open in iBooks again?

Comment: Which iOS version are you running? Is iBooks installed on the phone? Is the screen really blank or is it just the first (empty page) of the book you are seeing (try to scroll with a finger)?